Code gives type mismatch in one sub but not another
Hello I have a userform that includes 3 comboboxes: TaskStartTime, TaskFinishTime and Task_Duration.
The plan is you change the start or finish value in the userform and the duration value changes per the code below, except that the second sub: TaskStartTime_Change throws a type mismatch error for the line:
FinishTime = TaskFinishTime.value.
Strangely the exact same code is in the first sub and if I comment out the second sub there are no errors and the first sub works fine.
'first sub
Private Sub TaskFinishTime_Change()
    Dim FinishTime As Date
    Dim StartTime As Date
    Dim Duration As Date

    FinishTime = TaskFinishTime.value
    StartTime = TaskStartTime.value
    
    Duration = FinishTime - StartTime

    Task_Duration.value = Format(Duration, "h:mm")

End Sub

'second sub
Private Sub TaskStartTime_Change()
    Dim FinishTime As Date
    Dim StartTime As Date
    Dim Duration As Date

    FinishTime = TaskFinishTime.value
    StartTime = TaskStartTime.value

    Duration = FinishTime - StartTime

    Task_Duration.value = Format(Duration, "h:mm")

End Sub

I know it must be staring me in the face but for the life of me I can't see it. I do use formating when pre-filling the userform, and I've looked at that, but it's the exact same code so why would it behave differently in different subs?
I checked that the combobox rowsource is exactly the same for both TaskStartTime and TaskFinishTime
I tried a third sub to calculate finish time based on start time and duration, it also throws the mismatch error.
My current workaround is to use an On Error Resume Next for the problem sub, and when I do it all works fine, but is this really the right thing to do?
Can anyone suggest possible areas/errors to check for?

FinishTime = TaskFinishTime.Value is failing because the value of TaskFinishTime.Value cannot be converted to a date and so cannot be assigned to FinishTime.  You can add msgbox TaskFinishTime.Value before FinishTime = TaskFinishTime.Value to see its value.  If initially it has no value set in the UI then it will be "" which also cannot be converted to a date.  If this is indeed the problem then consider only assigning a value to FinishTime if the combobox has a valid date selected, for example by using If IsDate(TaskFinishTime.Value) Then ...

Yes, @alex-k you are correct thanks, it has no value on the second sub, but I don't understand why this is the case if it does have one for the first sub? I set the initial value in the calling sub and it shows up in the UI if I ignore the error?

It's likely that the change event is being called before TaskFinishTime has been populated. Try using a default value in both controls as a "starting point" - also given that the code is identical in both, move the functionality into another sub e.g. CalcDuration and call that sub from each of the Change events

Thanks @CHill60, yes I was formating the times as they were entered which was calling the change event for TaskStartTime before TaskFinishTime was entered dah. I put the code into a separate sub as you suggested and only call it if TaskFinishTime <> ""

As suggest by @CHill60 in my Userform_Activate sub the TaskStartTime value is loaded first and this calls TaskStartTime_Change before the finish time value even exists, hence the error.
The TaskFinishTime_Change sub works fine because both values are already set.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
